# Completely restore access control to defaults for WindowsApps folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, acl

I gave myself ownership of `C:/Program Files/WindowsApps` so I could poke around in there. I started running into issues though, and tried to give ownership back to `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller`. This didn't work, so I ran `icacls "C:/Program Files/WindowsApps" /q /c /t /reset` both in an administrator console and a bootable startup repair console. Both have the same issue. The GUI gives error messages saying access is denied, `icacls` lists about 2000 files that had "Access is denied" errors (in both terminals).

Other thinks I've tried: `wsreset`, `sfc /scannow`, and the Windows Troubleshooter.

Hulu is the main concern here. I'm using a friend's account, so I don't have the password and can't just completely reset the app. I get an error when trying to watch a show.

Is there a way I can restore the `WindowsApps` folder to the defaults (no system restores) or am I screwed?

Comment: Sadly, you will have to perform a Reset on your installation.

Comment: What issues did you see when you take ownership for that folder?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Hulu was giving me an error when trying to play a show saying to restart the app, EarTrumpet didn't start on startup and gave me an error message immediately.

Comment: @Biswapriyo "Please restart the app." I think I read something online about this being called DJ6, but it didn't say that for me.

Comment: Doers uninstalling and reinstalling solve your issue?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I don't want to do that because it would reset the password.

Comment: Are you sure that entering in elevated cmd the following doesn't work : `icacls "folder" /setowner "NT Service\\TrustedInstaller" /T /C`.